# How to exclude grails global dependency

Tags: grails, dependencies, grails-config

Grails has bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:138 as global dependency

```
+--- org.grails:grails-docs:2.3.3
|    \--- org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:R8
|    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-gdoc-engine:1.0.1
|    \--- com.lowagie:itext:2.0.8
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:138
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:138
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
```

But my app need bcprov-jdk15on-149. When I added it as dependency it doesn't evict old version

```
dependencies {
    build 'org.bouncycastle:bcpg-jdk15on:1.49'
    build 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.49'
}
```

I tried a lot of variants to exclude it but no one works

```
inherits("global") {
    //excludes 'grails-docs'

    excludes 'org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:138'
    excludes 'bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:138'
    excludes 'bcmail-jdk14-138.jar'
    excludes 'bcmail-jdk14'
    excludes 'bcmail'

    excludes 'bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:138'
    excludes 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:138'
    excludes 'bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:138'
    excludes 'bcprov-jdk14-138.jar'
    excludes 'bcprov-jdk14'
    excludes 'bcprov'
    excludes 'bouncycastle'
}
```

The only way to made it work – exclude whole 'grail-docs' dependency.

**How exclude only old bcprov-jdk14:138?**

**Or how to do that the new(bcprov-jdk15on-149) evict old(bcprov-jdk14:138)?**

Comment: Try `compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcpg-jdk15on:1.49'`. The newer version should be used.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I've already tried it and It haven't worked. It seems that problem in 'maven' dependency resolver(that grails used since 2.3) because with 'ivy' resolver everything works fine.

Comment: If you change in BuildConfig.groovy to use Ivy it works? Then I think you should raise a Jira.

Comment: Anyone has an answer for this issue ? I am also stuck...

Answer (score 10):

It seems to be a reported bug >> http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10640

I found a workaround by overriding the `com.logwagie.itext` dependency.

```
dependencies {
    // add this line
    build("com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7") { excludes "bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:138", "org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.38" }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: How this exclusion can be effective in a plugin that will be used by others ?

Comment: the above worked for me on Grails 2.5.6, but I used `build("com.lowagie:itext:2.0.8") { excludes "bcprov-jdk14" }`

Comment: How do you find all the packages that are including an old library?