# Prevent jar duplication while distZip Gradle task

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I have a Gradle project, which has plenty of dependencies from different repositories (`mavenCentral`, `jcenter`). After successful `distZip` task execution and inspecting a zip archive, I've found, that certain jars was duplicated in `lib` folder:

1. bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar and bcprov-jdk14-138.jar
2. bcmail-jdk14-1.38.jar and bcmail-jdk14-138.jar

Jar tuples has the same size and content.
I suppose this was happened because in different repositories those dependencies has different file names.
How can I prevent jars duplication in zip file when performing `distZip` task? Could it be a default functionality for distZip task or some option to enable?

As a workaround I believe I can write some kind of `distZip` task handler and 'squeeze' dependencies jar tuples (which may have two, three and more copies) to leave just one using some Groovy scripting, but I wanna know is it a default solution?

Comment: My current suggestion is: 1) Find dependencies that has `bcmail` and `bcprov` transitive dependenies, especially if they are located in different repos; 2) add exclude directive for one of this dependencies - to exclude `bouncy castle` libraries.

Comment: The problem like this is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21315957/1828296

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21315957/1828296, I found dependency which has transitive dependency to Bouncy castle libraries - it was `com.lowagie:itext` - by issuing `gradle dependencies` and searching by `1.38` and `138` values.

Then I made exclusions to this dependency like this:

`compile ('com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7+') {
  exclude group: "bouncycastle"
}`

Also added newest Bouncy Castle versions:

`compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.54+'
 compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15on:1.54+'
 compile 'org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk15on:1.46+'`

After `distZip` there was no old version or doubles of jars - just modern versions.